# CanCanCan and rails: restrict allowed values for enum attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, ruby-on-rails-6, cancancan

I'm using CanCanCan in a rails 6 application. I know that I can restrict the list of attributes that specific users are allowed to edit.

However, is there also a way to restrict the allowe *values* of an attribute?

More specifically I have a `User` class with a role attribute like this:

```
class  User < ApplicationRecord
  enum role: [:author, :editor, :admin]
end
```

When creating and updating users, I don't want users to be able to "upgrade" their own role – for instance, an editor should not be able to make himself admin, or create a new admin user.

Currently I have worked around this issue in my `UsersController` like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource
  def create
    if current_user.editor? and @user.admin?
      raise CanCan::AccessDenied.new('Cannot create admin user!', action: :create, subject: @user)
    end

    # ...
  end
end
```

However, that obviously means that I cannot use the `can?` and `cannot?` methods. So I wondered if there was a more elegant way to implement this using CanCanCan directly?

Comment: `cannot :create, User, role: 'admin'` should work for creating a new User, but editing won't be restricted by this if I understand the docs correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try! It's better then nothing I guess…